# What is the most portable way to check whether a trigger exists in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, information-schema

I'm looking for the **most portable** method to check for existence of a trigger in MS SQL Server. It needs to work on at least SQL Server 2000, 2005 and preferably 2008.

The information does not appear to be in INFORMATION_SCHEMA, but if it is in there somewhere, I would prefer to use it from there.

I do know of this method:

```
if exists (
    select * from dbo.sysobjects 
    where name = 'MyTrigger' 
    and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTrigger') = 1
) 
begin

end
```

But I'm not sure whether it works on all SQL Server versions.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This works on SQL Server 2000 and above

```
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('{your_trigger}'), 'IsTrigger') = 1
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Note that the naive converse doesn't work reliably:

```
-- This doesn't work for checking for absense
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('{your_trigger}'), 'IsTrigger') <> 1
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

...because if the object doesn't exist at all, `OBJECTPROPERTY` returns `NULL`, and `NULL` is (of course) not `<> 1` (or anything else).

On SQL Server 2005 or later, you could use `COALESCE` to deal with that, but if you need to support SQL Server 2000, you'll have to structure your statement to deal with the three possible return values: `NULL` (the object doesn't exist at all), `0` (it exists but is not a trigger), or `1` (it's a trigger).

Comment: [Important Caveat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328(v=sql.100).aspx): "*Objects that are not schema-scoped, such as DDL triggers, cannot be queried by using OBJECT_ID.*"  The workaround in these cases is to use the `sys.triggers` view as @marc_s describes in his answer.

Answer (score 65):

There's also the preferred "sys.triggers" catalog view:

```
select * from sys.triggers where name = 'MyTrigger'
```

or call the sp_Helptrigger stored proc:

```
exec sp_helptrigger 'MyTableName'
```

But other than that, I guess that's about it :-)

Marc

**Update (for Jakub Januszkiewicz):**

If you need to include the schema information, you could also do something like this:

```
SELECT
    (list of columns)
FROM sys.triggers tr
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON tr.parent_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')   -- or whatever you need
```

Comment: `select * from sys.triggers where name = 'MyTrigger'` doesn't work for my (correctly working etc.) trigger, while wgw's `IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('{your_trigger}'), 'IsTrigger') = 1` does... MSSQL 2008 R2.

Comment: @JakubJanuszkiewicz: are you in the right DB when you run this?? `sys.triggers` always shows the trigger in your current DB - it doesn't show all triggers from all databases...

Comment: @marc-s: I was in the correct DB. I have found the problem - the `name` column in `sys.triggers` is just a name (without schema name), while `OBJECT_ID('...')` expects a schema-qualified name (at least if the schema if a non-default one, if I understand it right). So after I copied my working `OBJECT_ID('MySchema.MyTrigger')` to `select * from sys.triggers`, it didn't work. Filtering by just 'MyTrigger' works fine.

Comment: @marc-s: By the way, this also means that if you have more than one trigger with the same name in different schemas of a DB, `select * from sys.triggers` will give you a false positive. Something along the lines of `select * from sys.objects where type = 'TR' and schema_id = (select schema_id from sys.schemas where name = 'YourSchema') and name = 'YourTrigger'` will get the correct trigger.

Comment: This will not work in SQL Server 2000, as required in the question, as the sys... catalog views were introduced in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Also, `sys.tables` can be replaced with `sys.views` when for example a `instead of insert` trigger is created for view.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming it is a DML trigger:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('your_trigger', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Trigger exists'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Trigger does not exist'
END
```

For other types of objects (tables, views, keys, whatever...), see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx under 'type'.

Comment: This checks any object type, not only triggers.

Comment: it prints  'Trigger exists', works in sql server 2012

Answer (score 2):

Tested and doesn't work on SQL Server 2000:

```
select * from sys.triggers where name = 'MyTrigger'
```

---

Tested and works ok on SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005:

```
select * from dbo.sysobjects
where name = 'MyTrigger' and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTrigger')
```

Comment: FWIW, your `select * from dbo.sysobjects where name = 'MyTrigger' and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTrigger')` doesn't work for my correctly-functioning `after insert, delete` trigger on SQL-2000. The row is there in `sysobjects`, but `OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTrigger')` on its ID (as part of the above or separately just using its raw ID) gives `0`. Checking for `xtype = 'TR'` or `type = 'TR'` works.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer by marc_s:

if the *existence check* is intended prior to dropping or modifying the trigger in some way, use a direct TSQL `try/Catch` bock, as the fastest means.

For instance:

```
BEGIN TRY
    DROP TRIGGER MyTableAfterUpdate;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS erno WHERE erno = 3701; -- may differ in SQL Server < 2005
END CATCH;
```

The Error Message will be

```
Cannot drop the trigger 'MyTableAfterUpdate', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Then simply check if the Executed Result returned rows or not, which is easy in direct sql as well as the programmatic APIs (C#,...).

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to find a server scoped DDL Trigger on SQL Server 2014, you should try sys.server_triggers.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers WHERE name = 'your trigger name')
BEGIN
    {do whatever you want here}
END
```

If I told tou anything incorrect, please let me know.

Edit:
I didn't check for this dm on another versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Are trigger names forced to be unique in SQL server?

As triggers are by definition applied to a specific table would it not be more efficient to restrict the search to only the table in question?

We have a database with over 30k tables in it all of which have at least one trigger and may have more (bad DB design - quite probably, but it made sense years ago and didn't scale well)

I use

```
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers 
WHERE [parent_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tableName) 
AND [name] = @triggerName
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this syntax to check and drop trigger

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[SCHEMA_NAME].[TRIGGER_NAME]') AND type in (N'TR'))
DROP TRIGGER [SCHEMA_NAME].[TRIGGER_NAME]
```

Answer (score 0):

Generated by **Sql Server Management Studio**:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[RolesYAccesos2016_UsuariosCRM_trgAfterInsert]'))
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[RolesYAccesos2016_UsuariosCRM_trgAfterInsert]
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[RolesYAccesos2016_UsuariosCRM_trgAfterInsert] 
ON  [PortalMediadores].[dbo].[RolesYAccesos2016.UsuariosCRM]
FOR INSERT
AS  
...
```

For `select @@version`

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1797.0 (X64)   Jun  1 2011
>   15:43:18   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
>   (Hypervisor)