# How to delete trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to delete a trigger in SQL Server. Seems like it should be simple enough, but because there is a thing called a "delete trigger", a trigger that is invoked upon deletion, it seems impossible to find resources on how to actually delete an already existing trigger.

Comment: Just make sure you aren't dropping a trigger that is needed for data integrity. Dropping a trigger because it prevents you from doing something is often a clue that what you want to do is not a good idea. Never drop a trigger without consulting the dba.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[DROP TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258846%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> Removes one or more triggers from the current database...
>
> You can remove a trigger by dropping it or by dropping the trigger table. When a table is dropped, all associated triggers are also dropped. When a trigger is dropped, information about the trigger is removed from the sysobjects and syscomments system tables.
>
> Use DROP TRIGGER and CREATE TRIGGER to rename a trigger. Use ALTER TRIGGER to change the definition of a trigger...

Comment: Works! ;) Heh, thanks! I'll mark is as the correct answer in 11 minutes, StackOverflow prevents me from accepting it immediately.

Comment: Fyi. In sql, delete is a row operation, drop is a db object (for example, a trigger) operation.

Comment: Yeah, it's really obvious in retrospect.

Comment: Remember to add the Schema prefix if it isn't dbo. So if the schema is 'MySchema' write DROP TRIGGER MySchema.SomeTrigger

Answer (score 19):

To drop a trigger, this works:

```
DROP TRIGGER [trigger_name];
```

If you want to check weather trigger exist before a drop, then use:

```
SELECT * FROM [sys].[triggers] WHERE [name] = 'MyTrigger'
```

For more check out http://www.tsql.info/triggers/drop-trigger.php and https://stackoverflow.com/a/636470/2218697

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2016 and above

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [dbo].[trg]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-trigger-transact-sql

Comment: Looks like you cannot specify `[dbo].[Table]`.

Answer (score 1):

I can Drop a Trigger with the Following Query

```
DROP TRIGGER [Trigger_Name]

          (OR)            

DROP TRIGGER Trigger_Update
```

Hope this Must helpfull...

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [dbo].[trigger_name];
```